# Are people more likely to vote in swing states?

Tags: voter-turnout

I wonder how many people vote based on the chance it has to influence the outcome vs other reasons, and this seems like a good way to gather some information about this.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. It's a good idea to take the [Tour](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help). While this is a good question, I think it has already been asked [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/13506/in-first-past-the-post-winner-takes-all-elections-is-turnout-higher-in-marginal). If your question is different, you should edit it to show how.